# Filtering post-formats from the loop using new WP-Query();

Tags: filters, loop, post-formats

Hi i am currently building upon a theme that i have build previously for my blog.
The following code is to point to the latest post (the featured post). As this will have a different styling than all the other posts.
However. I would like to filter out the post-format: links using the WP-Query i have defined within the loop since it brings me a lot more flexibility.
How would i go around doin that?

```
 <?php $featured = new WP_Query();  $featured->query('showposts=1'); ?>
                    <?php while ($featured->have_posts()) : $featured->the_post(); ?>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" class="maintitle"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="btn">Read more &raquo;</a>
```

Best Regards
Lucas

Comment: do you mean "post_type"?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to exclude posts with a specific format using [WP_Query's `tax_query` parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

Eg.

```
$q_args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 1, 
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'post-format-link' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
$featured->query( $q_args );
```

Untested, but should do the trick..

Comment: Sorry the code didnt function as needed i got an error from calling the query at line 16 Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/www/dechowmedia.com/wp-content/themes/portfolio/index.php on line 16

Comment: The code i posted should only replace the `$featured->query('showposts=1');` part of your original code, incase that wasn't obvious/clear.

Comment: If you received the answer you were looking for, please mark this answer correct, and i welcome the edit as you were indeed correct regarding the term slug.